# Using pandas how to find the average of certain elements in a column based on their date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df`

```
index  Heads
as     4
as     3
as     2
as     5
as     3
cd     4
cd     5
cd     6
```

Using the below code I can get the output as :

```
avg = df['Heads'].groupby(df.index).mean()
df.reset_index().pivot_table(columns=["index"]).T

index  Heads
as     3.4   
cd     5
```

But I have an other data frame `df2` with an extra column of dates in it like:

```
index  date         Heads
as     01-02-2000   4
as     04-03-2002   3
as     09-01-2003   2
as     23-12-2010   5
as     14-04-2006   3
cd     04-01-2004   4
cd     04-05-2007   5
cd     04-05-2001   6
```

Here, I want to take the average of `Heads` as in the above case, but only consider the elements which fall in between the years 2000 to 2005. Hence, the expected output is:

```
index  Heads
as     3   
cd     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then is possible use `mean` with `level` parameter:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)


df = (df[df['date'].dt.year.between(2000, 2005)]
         .mean(level=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  index  Heads
0    as      3
1    cd      5
```

Or:

```
df = (df[df['date'].dt.year.between(2000, 2005)]
         .groupby(level=0).mean()
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  index  Heads
0    as      3
1    cd      5
```